# Clarification of Read and Write on a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety

In the context of this statement,

> A Dictionary can support
>   multiple readers concurrently, as long
>   as the collection is not modified.
>   Even so, enumerating through a
>   collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. In the rare
>   case where an enumeration contends
>   with write accesses, the collection
>   must be locked during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection
>   to be accessed by multiple threads for
>   reading and writing, you must
>   implement your own synchronization.

What does read and write mean? My understanding is that a read is an operation which looks up a key and provides a reference to it's value and a write is an operation which adds or removes a key value pair from the dictionary. However, I can't find anything conclusive that regarding this.

So the big question is, while implementing a thread safe dictionary, would an operation that updates the value for an existing key in the dictionary be consider a reader or writer? I plan to have multiple threads accessing unique keys in a dictionary and modifying their values, but the threads will not add/remove new keys.

The obvious implication, assuming modifying an existing value is not a write operation on the dictionary, is that my implementation of the thread safe dictionay can be a lot more efficient, as I would not need to get an exclusive lock every time I try to update the value to an existing key.

Usage of ConcurrentDictionary from .Net 4.0 is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

A major point not yet mentioned is that if `TValue` is a class type, the things held by a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` will be the *identities of `TValue` objects*.  If one receives a reference from the dictionary, the dictionary will neither know nor care about anything one may do with the object referred to thereby.

One useful little utility class in cases where all of the keys associated with a dictionary will be known in advance of code that needs to use it is:

```
class MutableValueHolder<T>
{
   public T Value;
}
```

If one wants to have multi-threaded code count how many times various strings appear in a bunch of files, and one knows in advance all the strings of interest, one may then use something like a `Dictionary<string, MutableValueHolder<int>>` for that purpose.  Once the dictionary is loaded with all the proper strings and a `MutableValueHolder<int>` instance for each one, then any number of threads may retrieve references to `MutableValueHolder<int>` objects, and use `Threading.Interlocked.Increment` or other such methods to modify the `Value` associated with each one, without having to write to the Dictionary at all.

Answer (score 2):

overwriting an existing value should be treated as a write operation

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @SliverNinja, seems to me that this answer addresses the core question “would an operation that updates the value for an existing key in the dictionary be consider a reader or writer?”.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can affect the results of another read should be considered a write.

Changing a key is most definitly a write since it will cause the item to move in the internal hash or index or however dictionaries do their O(log(n)) stuff...

What you might want to do is look at ReaderWriterLock

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx

Comment: A lot of the documentation I had read showed Reader/Writer lock to have shockingly poor performance, worse than just using a single lock. It looks like ReaderWriterLockSlim should be what you use if it's available or use something else. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Comment: @Erik -I agree, but would add: It is always a balance. It would have to depend on the other costs in the mix. If the amount of reading and writing are about equal then I would advise just using lock() - but if writing is rare - and it usually is then reader writer lock is probably fine. It will be easy to move to the Slim lock when they upgrade.  Profiling when you have a problem is the best way to get performance. Very often people spend days coding to save milliseconds per operation.

Comment: Agreed, sometimes developers spend too much trying to pre-optimize. I used the phrase "shockingly poor performance" to denote it seems to be not a subtle performance issue but a rather drastic one. It's usually considered better to avoid it rather than use it. At least, that seems to be a lot of the conclusions I see reached during various performance discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a value is conceptually a write operation. When updating a value with concurrent access where a read is performed before a write is completed, you read out an old value. When two writes conflict the wrong value may be stored.

Adding a new value could trigger a grow of the underlying storage. In this case new memory is allocated, all elements are copied into the new memory, the new element is added, the dictionary object is updated to refer to the new memory location for storage and the old memory is released and available for garbage collection. During this time, more writes could cause a big problem. Two writes at the same time could trigger two instances of this memory copying. If you follow through the logic, you'll see an element will get lost since only the last thread to update the reference will know about existing items and not the other items that were trying to be added.

ICollection [provides a member to synchronize access](http://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/using-syncroot-for-multithreaded-applications/) and the reference remains valid across grow/shrink operations.

Comment: This is an interesting point, if I declare a dictionary of <string,string> and insert ("Key1","Hello") then do directory["Key1"] = "This is a really really long string", would it have to re-allocate memory for value, or since the value is an oject, and memory has already been allocated for the object, it would be able to re-use that memory? I guess a lot would depend on the innards of the Dictionary object.

Comment: For Dictionary<string,string> the underlying storage is ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>. The fact that you've already inserted a value means a record was added to the ICollection (expanding its contents, increasing memory if needed). The contents is just a struct containing a reference to two string objects. Changing the dictionary value string to something else just creates a new string in memory and updates the KeyValuePair reference. No change to the IDictionary underlying storage size.

Comment: In addition, Insert will throw an exception if you try to insert the same key twice. This can happen easily in a multi-threaded environment where locking wasn't properly implemented. If you want to be safer, just accessing a non-existent key will cause it to be created. If it does exist it will be updated. No exception throwing. Use Insert if adding the same key is an actual error condition that you want to catch. directory.Insert("Key1", "Hello"); versus directory["Key1"] = "Hello";

Answer (score 0):

A read operation is anything that gets a key or value from a `Dictionary`, a write operation is anything that updates or adds a key or a value. So a process updating a key would be considered to be a writer.

A simple way to make a thread safe dictionary is to create your own implementation of `IDictionary` that simply locks a mutex and then forwards the call to an implementation:

```
public class MyThreadSafeDictionary<T, J> : IDictionary<T, J>
{
      private object mutex = new object();
      private IDictionary<T, J> impl;

      public MyThreadSafeDictionary(IDictionary<T, J> impl)
      {
          this.impl = impl;
      }

      public void Add(T key, J value) 
      {
         lock(mutex) {
             impl.Add(key, value);
         }
      }

      // implement the other methods as for Add
}
```

You could replace the mutex with a reader-writer lock if you are having some threads only read the dictionary.

Also note that `Dictionary` objects don't support changing keys; the only safe way to achieve want you want is to remove the existing key/value pair and add a new one with the updated key.

Comment: is there any reason to do this rather than use ConcurrentDictionary?

Answer (score -1):

Modifying a value is a write and introduces a race condition.

Let's say the original value of mydict[5] = 42.
One thread updates mydict[5] to be 112.
Another thread updates mydict[5] to be 837.

What should the value of mydict[5] be at the end?  The order of the threads is important in this case, meaning either you need to make sure the order is explicit or that they don't write.

Comment: What you are describing is not really a race condition - since well either way whoever does it last wins - and that would be the same if you locked access. A race condition would be something like: if(!dict.ContainsKey(5)) dict(5,new Value()) now there is a potential inconsistency generated.

Comment: @Neil I think it is a race condition, just not a race condition that the dictionary can deal with. I already code in place to guarentee that the type of race condition mentioned in the answer doesn't happen.

Comment: @Joshua - a race condition could occur within the dictionary code that implements 'mydict[5] = X' but there is no race condition existing between Serinus' 3 set statements. Who ever sets the value last wins - that is just a description of normal programing. A race condition occurs in a the case where you set state based on previous previously examination of state. On its own x=1 cannot generate a race condition x++ can.